# Applying read-only property to text field in some PDF edtor

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

Is it possible to set the read-only property of input text field in PDF editors ?

I am building PDF template with text input fields I am populating with client code. I don't wan't to enable user editing on input values.

I am using PDFPenPro tool which doesn't have ability to set the read-only property for input fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to set a PDF form field to read only. Adobe Acrobat is one tool that lets you do that.

To set a field to read only in Acrobat, you need to bring up the field properties. The general tab, has an option for read only. Selecting that and hitting "apply" should do the trick.

[Here](https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/how-to-set-form-fields-to-read-only) is a video tutorial on how to do it.